# Vega-Lite (Deneb/PowerBI): Is it possible to calculate a dividing "symmetry" line? (different to Regression Line)

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

This is more a question of curiosity. In PowerBI, in the analytics pane, you can apply the following dividing lines/areas:

[For the question, my PBIX file](https://github.com/PBIQueryous/PBIXs/blob/main/MoM/2022Wk49.pbix)

- Symmetry Line
- Ratio Line
- Trend Line

See example:

## PowerBI Viz[image: showing dividing analytical lines]

I noticed a post from a Tableau user, where they were able to create the dividing symmetry line. This doesn't appear possible in PBI, only the line between the two shaded areas:

## Tablaeu Viz[image: Tableau viz showing symmetry line]

In Deneb, I was only able to achieve the regression / trend line, but I'm wondering if it's possible to also calculate the symmetry and ratio lines?

## Deneb/PBI viz[image: Deneb viz showing regression/trend line]

[Here is the link to my PBIX file](https://github.com/PBIQueryous/PBIXs/blob/main/MoM/2022Wk49.pbix) - any help or guidance is greatly appreciated :)

```json
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Actual",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "axis": {
        "format": "0%",
        "formatType": "pbiFormat"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Estimate",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "axis": {
        "format": "0%",
        "formatType": "pbiFormat"
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Sign",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "range": ["black", "red", "blue"]
      },
      "legend": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "point"}},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "firebrick"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "Estimate",
          "on": "Actual"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Actual",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Estimate",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've searched the internet for documentation, but I've not seen anything on this topic, so I'm wondering now if it's even possible?

I think this might demonstrate what I need - I'll do some more thinking: `[Vega-lite Linear Regression][1]`

Comment: Nice charts. Do you know the formula used to calculate the ratio and symmetry lines? There is nothing built in so these values would have to be calculated and then manually added to any chart.

Comment: Thanks @DavideBacci, I'm done some further digging, I must admit, I love data, but I'm terrible at maths  - I've found some info on the calculations, but I can't quite make sense of it: "It's the line that goes through the origin and the point equal to SUM(Y) / SUM(X)"

And a community post:
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/ratio-line-in-scatter-chart/m-p/346555

Comment: I'll keep researching, there's some VL documentation on different regression line types, just having no look finding some concrete examples.

Comment: From that post, the ratio line seems simple enough to calculate and add. I'm not convinced of the value of it or what insight it brings though. If you want me to create a solution with a ratio line, I'm happy to have an attempt.

Comment: Thanks Davide, you make a valid point, on second thought it's not massively valuable, it's essentially the line of best fit where the two segments meet, which is made apparent by separating the two clusters into the red / blue anyways. I'm happy to follow your lead, I wouldn't want you to spend time on this when the reward is minimal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the symmetry shade in PBI is just a line that splits the chart in half when the x and y axis are the same.
How does this look?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ID": 1, "Actual": 0.2, "Estimate": 0.19, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 2, "Actual": 0.5, "Estimate": 0.55, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 3, "Actual": 0.3, "Estimate": 0.29, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 4, "Actual": 0.25, "Estimate": 0.26, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 5, "Actual": 0.22, "Estimate": 0.23, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 6, "Actual": 0.13, "Estimate": 0.12, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 7, "Actual": 0.18, "Estimate": 0.17, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 8, "Actual": 0.16, "Estimate": 0.16, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 9, "Actual": 0.31, "Estimate": 0.3, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 10, "Actual": 0.12, "Estimate": 0.11, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 11, "Actual": 0.14, "Estimate": 0.14, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 12, "Actual": 0.67, "Estimate": 0.27, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 13, "Actual": 0.24, "Estimate": 0.43, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 14, "Actual": 0.21, "Estimate": 0.2, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 15, "Actual": 0.68, "Estimate": 0.49, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 16, "Actual": 0.22, "Estimate": 0.21, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 17, "Actual": 0.17, "Estimate": 0.18, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 18, "Actual": 0.19, "Estimate": 0.2, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 19, "Actual": 0.23, "Estimate": 0.22, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 20, "Actual": 0.15, "Estimate": 0.45, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 21, "Actual": 0.29, "Estimate": 0.28, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 22, "Actual": 0.3, "Estimate": 0.31, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 23, "Actual": 0.28, "Estimate": 0.27, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 24, "Actual": 0.26, "Estimate": 0.25, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 25, "Actual": 0.62, "Estimate": 0.33, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 26, "Actual": 0.35, "Estimate": 0.34, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 27, "Actual": 0.33, "Estimate": 0.32, "Sign": "C"},
      {"ID": 28, "Actual": 0.37, "Estimate": 0.38, "Sign": "A"},
      {"ID": 29, "Actual": 0.39, "Estimate": 0.4, "Sign": "B"},
      {"ID": 30, "Actual": 0.7, "Estimate": 0.7, "Sign": "C"}
    ]
  },
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Actual",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "axis": {"format": "0%", "title": "Actual %","grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Estimate",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "axis": {"format": "0%", "title": "Estimate %","grid": false}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Sign",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"range": ["black", "red", "blue"]},
      "legend": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"ID": 1, "Start": 0}, {"ID": 2, "Start": 1}]},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Start",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"format": "0%", "title": ""}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Start",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"format": "0%", "title": ""}
        }
      },
      "layer": [{"mark": {"type": "area", "fill": "#ffcccc"}}]
    },
    {"mark": {"type": "circle", "tooltip": true}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "firebrick"},
      "transform": [{"regression": "Estimate", "on": "Actual"}],
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {"value": 0.4},
        "x": {"field": "Actual", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Estimate", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"fill": "#bfe5b6"}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing @APB Reports, I understand what's happening now, I think I misunderstood the PBI native scatter plots because the x and y axis are not both set to 0 & 100, so it skewed the dividing line, which made me think it was calculating something else. Brilliant. Thank you for your response.